# what happen if i hold a transaction for too long by not commiting it

Tags: vb.net, transactions, db2

I have a code

```
    Dim cmd As New DB2Command
    Dim trs As DB2Transaction = Nothing
    trs = ConnDB2.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)
    cmd.Transaction = trs
    cmd.Connection = ConnDB2
    cmd.CommandText = Query
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    While (true)

    End While

    trs.Commit()
```

I am doing this in multithread environment, when all thread's executeNonQuery gives me no error then the while loop will break and allow all transaction to commit together. I want to ask what will happen to transaction if the while loop execute like 5 minutes before allowing it to commit? Will the connection timeout or something else?

Comment: I don't think so, but doing so is usually a bad idea anyways.  You want transactions to be short.  It could be worse than timing out - you could get escalated to a full table-lock, which would make people hate you.  I also have a feeling that your multi-threading code isn't doing what you want - where is it, anyways?  This is clearly not the code you're actually using.  Why do you think you need multiple threads?  DBs can often transparently use threads to speed things up, regardless of what your application may be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two bad things that can happen in this situation.

First, each transaction keeps its locks until it is committed. This means that other threads or applications requesting to lock the same rows may either receive a lock timeout error or wait indefinitely, depending on their lock timeout settings.

Second, even in the absence of lock conflicts your database can experience what is called *log saturation*. A transaction log file cannot be reused or archived if it is in use by an uncommitted transaction, so the number of allocated log files will grow until it reaches the configured limit and then no new transaction can be initiated, so all database activities will essentially stop until you commit the oldest transaction.

As @Clockwork-Muse says, you want your transactions to be as short as possible. I cannot imagine the business reason for your intent to commit all threads' transactions simultaneously.